# snapshot replication - corrupted BCP files

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

Each night my SQLServer replication failed on a big table with the following error. It is failing on a different table each night but always on a relatively big table ( > 200,000 rows)

The process could not bulk copy into table '"dbo"."Table01"'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20037)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20037
**Field size too large

Batch send failed**
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Table01'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table01'. The duplicate key value is (0). (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2627)
Get help: http://help/2627
Failed to send batch after max errors (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 3621)
Get help: http://help/3621

Publication is configured on a SQL Server 2017 CU29 instance on a FCI Cluster which is hosted on one node  (the errors were also occurring with CU27)
"Push" Subscription is configured on a SQL Server 2017 CU29 instance on the same node of the cluster
Distributor is configured on the same instance of the subscription

Each morning I trigger the snapshot and all get fixed automatically.
I made the following tests:

- move the schedule of my snapshot from 0:30AM to 2:25AM -> same problem
- disable antivirus scan -> same problem
- disable filesystem backup on the drive used by the datafiles -> same problem
- one night the replication failed for one database which had 2 subscribers. the 2 subscribers were in failure using the same snapshot -> problem is not on the subscriber side
- insert the BCP files manually into the destination/subscriber database -> did not work

sometimes the error message varies :

The process could not bulk copy into table '"dbo"."Table02"'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20037)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20037
**Batch send failed**
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Table02'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table02'. The duplicate key value is (0). (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 2627)
Get help: http://help/2627
To obtain an error file with details on the errors encountered when initializing the subscribing table, execute the bcp command that appears below.  Consult the BOL for more information on the bcp utility and its supported options. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20253)
Get help: http://help/20253
bcp "DB02"."dbo"."Table02" in "\SERV02\SQL_Repldata\unc\SQL02_DB02_PUB_DB02_SN\20220727003003\Table0227f2adc_608#36.bcp" -e "errorfile" -t"\n<x$3>\n" -r"\n<,@g>\n" -m10000 -SLIRIO\ISTORE -T -w (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20253)
Get help: http://help/20253

I am pretty convinced that something occurs during the creation of the BCP files.
Can you help me?

Do you know a way to get more information during the creation of the BCP files or monitor the snapshot folder?

Thank you,
Vince

Comment: No my databases on the publisher have the option "is Read Committed Snapshot on" set to False. From my point of view, the PK violation is the result/consequence of a failed null insert because of the corrupted BCP. When I trigger another snapshot later it works fine. I wonder if the CommVault backup agent could generate a snapshot isolation on the publisher though.... thank you for your comment and suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was linked to the SMB share used by the replication to create/use the BCP Files.

The solution was to move the AD account used by the replication from its AD group directly to shared folder permissions and filesystem permissions in the security settings of the BCP files directory.

Answer (score 2):

### I think it's your isolation level

Since you are using the default `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level, and not `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` isolation (RCSI) level, the snapshot process is likely taking an inconsistent snapshot as it reads data out to create the file. The snapshot isn't corrupt--SQL Server is just beholden to the rules of the isolation level it is running under as it pulls the data. You can read more about [Read Committed](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-committed-isolation-level) and [RSCI](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation), but pay attention to the "Locking Read Committed Behaviours" section:

> The short-term shared locks used by the SQL Server locking read committed implementation provide very few of the guarantees commonly expected of a database transaction by T-SQL programmers. In particular, a statement running under locking read committed isolation:
>
> - Can encounter the same row multiple times;
> - Can miss some rows completely; and
> - Does not provide a point-in-time view of the data
>
> That list might seem more like a description of the weird behaviours you might associate more with the use of `NOLOCK` hints, but all these things really can, and do happen when using locking read committed isolation.

What is likely happening is that as your replication snapshot runs, it is "encountering the same row multiple times", because it "does not provide a point-in-time view of the data."

During the time that you are generating the replication snapshot, if there are processes that modify data (including index maintenance), you will be more likely to see these odd behaviors than generating the replication snapshot during a time of no/low data modification.

#### Confirming the problem

There are two ways that come to mind as easy ways to confirm that this is the problem.

- If you drop all constraints (including the PK) from `Table02` and manually load the snapshot files using `bcp.exe` from the command line, you should be able to confirm if there are duplicates in the file. \
- You can pre-create the table on the subscriber (without the PK or constraints), and set the article in your publication to truncate--rather than drop/recreate--when loading the data on the subscriber. You can do this with [`sp_changearticle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changearticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to change this, or you can change it in SSMS on the article properties. After changing, you will need to generate a new snapshot.

```
EXEC sp_changearticle 
    @publication            = 'MyPublicationName',
    @article                = 'Table02',
    @property               = 'pre_creation_cmd',
    @value                  = 'truncate'; -- or 'drop' or 'delete' or 'none'
```

### Possible fixes

The most reliable solution is to switch your publisher to use Read Committed Snapshot. This should ensure that the snapshot agent will properly bcp out a consistent snapshot that does not show the same row multiple times. Making this change can change application behavior subtly, so be sure you research & understand the change and impact before proceeding.

A second option (as you've found) is that you can just generate the snapshot at a different time when there is less data movement, so that you are less likely to run into this behavior where a row is read multiple times during replication snapshot creation.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain me in details. Very well appreciated. I am going to read, research and test before coming back to you. If it is the solution, I will have to understand what has changed in my environment because it has been running for more than 1 year without any replication problem and the DB activity has not changed much.

Comment: I have been doing the following tests:
In production, I created a test database which is replicated to the same place as others. I copied 3 big tables to this test database. 
For this test database, a snapshot occurs every hour. There is no application connecting to this test database (except for the backup tool and SCOM).
This morning at 11:10AM, the replication broke.
I configured the option "Allow snapshot isolation" to true on that database. We'll see if it breaks again. If it does break, I will try the option READ_COMMIT_SNAPSHOT.

Comment: The "Allow Snapshot Isolation" setting is a different thing. The similar naming makes this confusing, but SNAPSHOT isolation needs the application to be aware of it and invoke use of the snapshot. Replication/BCP don't do that. You will need to use **READ COMMITTED** SNAPSHOT.