# BCP out significant throughput drop while using read committed snapshot isolation

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am running bcp to output data to a file. I cannot run bcp out in read committed mode because of the reasons mentioned in [snapshot replication - corrupted BCP files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315798/snapshot-replication-corrupted-bcp-files).

I tried using read committed snapshot isolation but found that there was a significant throughput drop. With RC, I am getting throughput of 52 MB/s. However, with RCSI, I am getting throughput of only 35 MB/s.

I tried a normal select * with RC and RCSI and I got throughput of 25 and 26 MB/s respectively, which indicates that there is not much impact while reading snapshots from *tempdb*.

I wanted to understand what internal architecture in bcp makes the throughput drop so high.

The question is more about the relative numbers than the absolutes, but if it helps, I am using SSD persistent disk for both read and write. Write throughput of the disk to which I am writing is rated at 400 MB/s.

**DB Version**: SQL Server 2019 Standard CU16-GDR 
**Data table**: ORDER_LINE from standard [TPCC](https://www.tpc.org/tpcc/) database
**BCP version**: 17.10.0001.1
**BCP command used**:  `bcp ORDER_LINE OUT out/order_line.dat -S tcp:127.0.0.1,1434 -U {username} -P {password} -d TPCC -t "," -r "\n" -F 1 -f format/order_line-n.fmt`
**Format file generated using**: `bcp ORDER_LINE format nul -S tcp:127.0.0.1,1434 -U {username} -P {password} -d TPCC -n -f format/order_line-n.fmt`
**Metrics measured**: network sent_bytes_count

There is a write load on the database generated by [HammerDB](https://hammerdb.com/). I ran bcp once using Read committed isolation level, then set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to ON and then ran bcp again.

Comment: Ok that should explain it.  With RCSI the BCP runs concurrently with the other workload.  Without it the other workload becomes blocked by the BCP query and so isn’t using server resources.